# how to create an SQL query to sum by user id for a specific month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the folowing table

```
idOrder | idCust |Name | OrderDate     | affId | Sku | desc |quantity |unitPrice | subtotal
224332  | 4657   |Jeff |6/5/2014 11:09 | 1     |1344 |---  | 6       |41.25     | 247.5
224332  | 4657   |Jeff |6/5/2014 11:09 | 1     |1388 |---  | 3       |41.25     | 123.75
224388  | 4656   |Jane |6/5/2014 08:09 | 1     |1388 | --- | 6       |41.25     | 247.5
224332  | 4659   |Tom  |7/5/2014 11:09 | 1     |1222 |---  | 6       |41.25     | 247.5
224332  | 4657   |Jeff |7/7/2014 11:09 | 1     |1344 |---  | 3       |41.25     | 123.75
224388  | 4656   |Jane |7/5/2014 08:09 | 1     |1222 |---  | 6       |41.25     | 247.5
```

I need to summarize the table to have 
all of the total purchases for june totall purchace that was of sku# 1344 for that month
so i would have the following in a new table for the month of June

```
IdCust | Name| Total Purchase (dollar amount) |  Total  of sku# 1334 (dolar amount)|
4657   |Jeff | sum of all the above for june  | some of just that sku for june|
4656   |Jane | sum of all the above for june  | some of just that sku for june|
4659   |Tom  | sum of all the above for june  | some of just that sku for june|
```

Comment: You are looking for a [pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+pivot) where you'll create the columns based on the month value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with conditional aggregation:

```
select idCust, Name, sum(quantity * unitPrice) as TotalPurchase,
       sum(case when sku = 1344 then quantity * unitPrice end) as TotalPurchase_1344
from table t
where date >= '2014-06-01' and date < '2014-07-01'
group by idCust, Name;
```